# MySql - Json_extract: count elements

Tags: mysql, json

I'm working with JSON type column in MySQL. I have a table with two columns id and jsondata (json type column). Follows an example of my json row:

```
{
  "id": "35",
    "var": [
      {
        "inf": "VALUE1",
        "prod": {
          "xProd": "PRODUCT 1",
        },
        "nItem": 1
      },
      {
        "inf": "VALUE2",
        "prod": {
          "xProd": "PRODUCT 2",
        },
        "nItem": 2
      },
    ]
}
```

How is the sentence to extract size of "var" property? In my case, the var property has 2 values insides: "inf: VALUE1" and "inf:VALUE2".

My goals is create a table with this format:

```
ID     QTD_VAR     INF
35        2        VALUE1, VALUE2
```

If I use the code below, I can extract VALUE2 from my JSON:

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(`jsondata` , '$.id.var[1].INF')
from tmp;
```

But the problem is I don't know how many elements "var" can have in each row.

Any help, is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some [12.16.1 JSON Function Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html). You will need to adjust everything you require.

Only some ideas:

```sql
SELECT
  CAST(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@`json`, '$.id')) AS SIGNED) `ID`,
  JSON_LENGTH(@`json`, '$.var') `QTD_VAR`,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(@`json`, '$.var[*].inf'), '[\\[\\]"]', '') `INF`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba2f24b2fe44f9b1a335b836b2000a02).